# Need to pass a parameter to class method being used by setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with the setInterval method in the sense that I need to pass its first parameter (the function being set to an interval) a parameter of its own.

I've included the class in which I am trying to achieve this.

Granted the function itself works and I am getting a response from ajax, but it doesn't know where to put it. Anyone know how to achieve this?

```
function message_console(log_id, person_2_msg_id) {
    this.user_id = log_id;
    this.person_messaged_id = person_2_msg_id;
    this.input_id = "send_to_" + person_2_msg_id;
    this.messages_id = "chat_with_" + person_2_msg_id;

    this.get_messages = function get_messages(id) { // remember to add the id as parameter
                                                    // to this function that will receive
                                                    // this responseText
        //ajax here - get messages
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                _(id).innerHTML = x.responseText;
            }
        }
        x.open("POST", "parse/private_msg.php");
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        x.send("get_messages=true&to=" + person_2_msg_id);
    }

    setInterval(this.get_messages, 3000);   // need to figure out how to pass para here - with
                                            // the function as a variable and in oop - not sure
                                            // how - ask adam asap
    setInterval(this.get_messages(parameter), 3000);    //this does not work

    this.container += '<div class="msg_module">';
    this.container += '<div class="message" id="' + this.messages_id + '">' +
        this.get_messages(this.messages_id) + '</div>';
    this.container += '<input type="text" onkeypress="submit_private_msg(event,\'' +
        this.user_id + '\',\'' + this.person_messaged_id + '\',\'' + this.messages_id +
        '\',\'' + this.input_id + '\')" class="msg_head" id="' + this.input_id + '" >';
    this.container += '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see MDN document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval), the syntax below:

> var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
>
> var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);

#### option 1:

```
setInterval( this.get_messages,3000, parameter);
```

#### options 2:

```
setInterval( function(){ this.get_messages.call(this, parameter) } ,3000 );
```

Function call method see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
setInterval(function() { this.get_messages(parameter); }.bind(this), 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your function call in another `anonymous function` as follows:

```
var me = this;
setInterval(function(){
    me.get_messages(parameter);
}, 3000);
```

Note that we are using a `me` variable which makes reference to the `this` of the first function.